# What's the best GCP product for deploying multiple long running web scrapers?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have multiple web scrapers and each can run for up to 32 hours.

From what it seems **Cloud Function**, **Cloud Run** and **App Engine** can not handle this kind of workload because of the run time limits(15-60 min) and instances not being guaranteed to run constantly. **Compute Engine** seems like the right product but the pricing estimate is way above 100€/month which in the long run makes it more feasible to get a local server and run the scrapers on it.

Is there a product I am missing?

What is the GCP product that can meet my use case?

Answer (score 1):

You can spin up a server (compute engine), run your processes, then terminate it.